# Update Bool Property Based on INotifyDataErrorInfo in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-annotations, inotifydataerrorinfo

In my Previous Question, I got a solution how to manually check the Validation Result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031783/screen-validation-with-data-annotations-on-button-click-in-using-inotifydataerro/39033124#39033124

I'm having a Model `Person`, it contains three properties `FirstName` (required), `MiddleName` (optional) and `LastName` (required).

Now I changed My Code slightly

```
public class PersonViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyDataErrorInfo {

    private string _personObj = string.Empty;

    public Person PersonObj
    {
        get { return _personObj; }
        set { _personObj= value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool IsValidObject
    {
        get 
        { 
            var context = new ValidationContext(EmpInfo, null, null);
            bool flag = Validator.TryValidateObject(EmpInfo, context, null, true);
            return flag;
        }
    }

    public ICommand SaveDataCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegatingCommand(SaveData);
            }
        }

    public void SaveData
        {
            // Validate Data;
        }

}
```

The Model Class: Person

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML is

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PersonObj.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
 ,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

<TextBox Text="{Binding PersonObj.MiddleName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
 ,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

<TextBox Text="{Binding PersonObj.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
 ,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

<Button Content="Save" IsDefault="True" IsEnabled="{Binding IsValidObject}" Command="{Binding SaveDataCommand}" />
```

The Property `IsValidObject` Initially works fine. If I update the Value in `FirstName` and `LastName`, then the property `IsValidObject` is not updating the result in UI.

I used one more approach

```
public class PersonViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyDataErrorInfo {

    private string _personObj = string.Empty;

    public Person PersonObj
    {
        get { return _personObj; }
        set { _personObj= value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool IsValidObject
    {
        get 
        { 
            var context = new ValidationContext(EmpInfo, null, null);
            bool flag = Validator.TryValidateObject(EmpInfo, context, null, true);
            return flag;
        }
    }

    public ICommand SaveDataCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegatingCommand(SaveData, ValidateEmployeeObject);
            }
        }


    public bool ValidateEmployeeObject()
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(EmpInfo, null, null);
        bool flag = Validator.TryValidateObject(EmpInfo, context, ErrorResult, true);
        return flag;
    }

    public void SaveData
        {
            // Validate Data;
        }

}
```

Here I introduced a Method `ValidateEmployeeObject()`, it returns `TRUE` / `FALSE` as similar to the Property `IsValidObject`. I binded this Method in **`CanExecute`** Block of `SaveDataCommand` as proposed by @adminSoftDK in the comment part. This approach too fails...

How could I update the Save Button to make Enable based on the above validation.

Comment: You've got at least couple of problems here. First of all i doubt it compiles, because IsValidObject is a string, but you are trying to return bool. Secondly IsEnabled cannot bind to string, unless you have converter. There is an easier approach, your command you can have CanExecute, and your IsValidObject should then RaiseCanExecute. And button will become disabled or enabled automatically, you would not have to mess with is Enabled.

Comment: @adminSoftDK - Its a `bool` property. Typing mistake...

Comment: @adminSoftDK CanExecute approach too not functioning... Kindly assist me...

Answer (score 0):

If you try something like this

```
public PersonViewModel()
{
   SaveDataCommand = new DelegatingCommand(SaveData, ()=> flag);
}

bool flag;

public bool IsValidObject
{
    get 
    { 
        var context = new ValidationContext(EmpInfo, null, null);
        flag = Validator.TryValidateObject(EmpInfo, context, null, true);
        SaveDataCommand.RaiseCanExecute() // don't know what type of command you have but you should have a method which you can call something with Canexecute
        return flag;
    }
}

public bool ValidateEmployeeObject()
{
  return IsValidObject;
}

public ICommand SaveDataCommand { get;  }
```

I'm not very familiar with INotifyDataErrorInfo and I don't know at what point is your IsValidObject is called, but i think something like the above should work.